# React native (expo) have a different navigation bar color for each page (on Android)

Tags: react-native, expo

Android phones that have a navigation bar like that from the iPhone, have the default background color as white, which looks really off if my screen's background color is different than white, so I need to change the background color depending on the background color of my screen.

Currently I'm using expo to change that color whenever a screen component loads, but that doesn't work when I'm navigating back to a previous screen.

This is what I have in all of my screens (only with different colors to match my background)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync(colors.main);
    }
  }, []);
```

How can I make this run when I navigate back to a screen that's already loaded? Or what's another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using `useIsFocused` from `@react-navigation/native` to tell when the user came back to the screen and then calling  `NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync` again

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by importing `StatusBar` from React-Native;

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(primary_color)
return (
...
)}
```

Or you can set it within the return function as such;

```
return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <StatusBar
    animated={true}
    backgroundColor="red"
    barStyle={statusBarStyle}
    showHideTransition={statusBarTransition}
    hidden={hidden} />
    ...
```

Ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

Comment: That only seems to be for the Status Bar (Top part of the phone), I need to change the background color of the Navigation Bar  (Bottom part of the phone)

Comment: Hmm in that case, you may need to use a package as I don't think RN has the option to change that - it used to. Maybe something like this: https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/thebylito-react-native-navigation-bar-color